# Find end replace content in all tags

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I want to find and replace all nodes in XML files. I tried this:

```
def modify_xml_content(request_body, node, content)
    doc = Nokogiri::XML(request_body)
    node = doc.search(node).first
    node.content = content
    puts "Modifying #{node}"
    doc.to_xml
  rescue
    request_body
  end
```

***Example XML***

```
<billing_address>
    <first_name>Max</first_name>
    <last_name>Mustermann</last_name>
    <address1>Muster Str. 12</address1>
    <zip_code>10178</zip_code>
    <city>New York</city>
    <state>WA</state>
    <country>US</country>
  </billing_address>
  <shipping_address>
    <first_name>Max</first_name>
    <last_name>Mustermann</last_name>
    <address1>Muster Str. 12</address1>
    <zip_code>10178</zip_code>
    <city>New York</city>
    <state>WA</state>
    <country>US</country>
  </shipping_address>
```

How I can find and replace all content in tags  for example not only the first found matching tag?

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What is the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Do `each` instead of `first`:

```
doc.search(node).each do |n|
  n.content = content
end
```